# PHP: Incorrect strtotime()

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I had gone through various stackoverflow solutions and other blogs but still it doesn't fix my problem.

Let's say that the date today is: **2013-12-28** and I want to get the date after 1 month and it is supposed to display **2014-01-28**.

```
$date = date('o-m-d');
$final = date('o-m-d', strtotime("+1 month", $date));
echo $final;
```

Above is my code. It returns ***02/01/1970***.

I have also tried the mktime method but still it displays the 1970 output.

What am I doing wrong?

BTW. I am working this on a hosted server.

Thanks ahead. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the current date +1 month use:

```
$final = date('o-m-d', strtotime("+1 month"));
```

Or with a given date:

```
$date = date('o-m-d');
$final = date('o-m-d', strtotime($date . " +1 month"));
echo $final;
```

If you want to use the second parameter of strtotime it has to be a timestamp.

Comment: This worked. THanks a lot! I need to remember that there wouldn't be a second parameter then ;)

Comment: @Sarah: I corrected myself. The second parameter CAN take a timestamp.

Answer (score 3):

Use [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) function [modify](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-modify.php)

```
$date = new DateTime( 'o-m-d' );  
echo $date->modify( '+1 month' )->format('o-m-d');
```

Answer (score 2):

### Go the **`OOP`** way..

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime('2013-12-28');
$date->add(new DateInterval('P1M'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d'); //prints 2014-01-28
```